# How to cancel a task from a TaskCompletionSource?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to create an async ProducerConsumerCollection and for that, I'm using this msdn page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173.aspx (bottom of the page)).

I'm now trying to add a timeout, here is what I do :

```
    public async Task<T> TakeWithTimeout(int timeout)
    {
            Task<T> takeTask = this.Take();

            if (timeout <= 0 || takeTask == await Task.WhenAny(this.tasks.Take(), Task.Delay(timeout)))
            {
                return await takeTask;
            }
            else
            {
                // Timeout
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with this code is that, in case of timeout, it does not cancel the task created by the Take() method.

Since this task has been "created" by the TaskCompletionSource, I cannot give it a cancellationToken?

So, how to proceed to cancel it and properly implement this Take with timeout ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing a cancel-safe `async`-friendly producer/consumer collection is non-trivial. What you need to do is change `Take` to accept a `CancellationToken` as a parameter, and it should register a handler so that when it is cancelled the `TaskCompletionSource` is cancelled.

I highly recommend you use `BufferBlock<T>`, which has cancellation support built-in.

If you can't use TPL Dataflow (e.g., you're working in a PCL or have target platforms unsupported by Dataflow), then you can use the producer/consumer collections in my open-source [AsyncEx library](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com) (such as [`AsyncProducerConsumerQueue`](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncProducerConsumerQueue&referringTitle=Documentation) or [`AsyncCollection`](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncCollection&referringTitle=Documentation)). These are both based on [`AsyncLock`](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncLock&referringTitle=AsyncMonitor) and [`AsyncConditionVariable`](https://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncConditionVariable&referringTitle=AsyncMonitor), a design I describe briefly [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/async-producer-consumer-queue-2-more.html) (which does not get into the cancellation details). The key behind supporting cancellation in a producer/consumer collection with this design is to support cancellation in `AsyncConditionVariable.WaitAsync`; once your condition variable type supports cancellation, then your collection will easily support it, too.

Comment: It's for training purpose only, so I want to implement my own class :)

I added the cancellation token `ct` into the method, and the following line (if `m_collection.Count == 0`) : `ct.Register(() => tcs.TrySetResult(default(T)));`

This TrySetResult is properly called, but the canceled task does not seem to be properly closed :(

Comment: You also have to think about what would happen when a `Put` retrieves a TCS from the waiting list that has already been cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to post my solution to the question **How to cancel a task from a TaskCompletionSource** because that is what I needed myself.

I'm guessing this could be used for your specific need, but it's not tied to a specific timeout functionality, so this is a general solution (or so I hope).

This is an extension method:

```
    public static async Task WaitAsync<T>(this TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs, CancellationToken ctok)
    {

        CancellationTokenSource cts = null;
        CancellationTokenSource linkedCts = null;

        try {

            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cts.Token, ctok);

            var exitTok = linkedCts.Token;

            Func<Task> listenForCancelTaskFnc = async () => {
                await Task.Delay(-1, exitTok).ConfigureAwait(false); 
            };

            var cancelTask = listenForCancelTaskFnc();

            await Task.WhenAny(new Task[] { tcs.Task, cancelTask }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            cts.Cancel();

        } finally {

            if(linkedCts != null) linkedCts.Dispose();

        }

    }
```

Usage:

```
    async Task TestAsync(CancellationToken ctok) {

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        if (somethingOrTheOther) {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }

        await tcs.WaitAsync(ctok);

    }
```

The idea is to have a supervisory async Task waiting essentially forever until it is cancelled, which we can use to 'exit early' in case the `TaskCompletionSource` is not yet satisfied, but we need to exit anyhow due to a cancel request.

The supervisory Task is guaranteed to be cancelled at the end of `WaitAsync` regardless how it falls out of the `WhenAny`.  Either the `TaskCompletionSource` is satisfied with a result, and `WhenAny` completes, briefly leaving the supervisory sleeper task in tact until the next line where `cts.Cancel()` is called, **or** it was cancelled with the `exitToken`, which is a combined token of the passed in `ctok` or the internal one `cts.Token`.

Anyhow, I hope this makes sense -- please let me know if this code has  any problems...

Comment: Cancellation tokens can be tricky, especially in situations where the cancellation token is never triggered. What happens when user code calls `TestAsync(CancellationToken.None)`? Also, note that `CreateLinkedTokenSource` is one of the few APIs where you *must* dispose the resulting cts, or you can easily run into memory leaks.

Comment: I have a more robust solution [here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Tasks/blob/1aa070bca30c1b5a6fab05b2b98142215e17ca84/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/CancellationTokenTaskSource.cs) - [usage](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Tasks/blob/1aa070bca30c1b5a6fab05b2b98142215e17ca84/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskExtensions.cs#L78).

Comment: @StephenCleary I don't see a problem with passing in `CancellationToken.None`.  That really just means you depend on the TaskCompletionSource to eventually get triggered.  I fixed the code to dispose of the `CreateLinkedTokenSource`.  Thanks for that.  Also thanks for the alternative implementation.  It's using stuff I generally don't use, so a bit more advanced than my implementation.  Is there anything else wrong with the code as I have mine?  What is "less robust" at this point about my implementation?

Comment: If the user passes in `CancellationToken.None`, then you have a task that never completes - in other words, a memory leak. Why not just use `CancellationToken.Register`?

Comment: I need to read up on CancellationToken.Regstier... honest answer is I didn't know about it.  But you are incorrect about your assertion, still.  If you pass in CancellationToken.None, the caller is indicating they never want to cancel the task from the outside, which means that the internal `cts.Cancel();` will wake up the sleeper thread and exit it.  That line is always called.  So I still don't see the memory leak.  I'll look at CancellationToken.Register.  Just have not used that yet.  :)

Comment: The sleeper thread does not monitor `exitTok` - only `ctok`, which would never be canceled.

Comment: Ooops.  That was totally not what I wanted.  Thanks!  Fixed in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

A potentially slightly less complicated/more flexible way to do it would be to have the `TaskCompletionSource` code do its thing, and then at the point at which you're ready to return the task, you can "attach" the cancellation to it using a similar technique to Bernie's answer.

Extension Methods:

```cs
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Apply cancellation support to an arbitrary task
    /// </summary>
    public static async Task OrCancelledBy(this Task task, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        await Task.WhenAny(
            task, 
            Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken) // Wait forever until cancellation
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// Apply cancellation support to an arbitrary task that returns TResult
    /// </summary>
    public static async Task<TResult> OrCancelledBy<TResult>(this Task<TResult> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        async Task<TResult> WaitUntilCancelled(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            await Task.Delay(-1, ct); // Wait forever until cancellation
            return default!;
        }

        return await await Task.WhenAny(task, WaitUntilCancelled(cancellationToken));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
    async Task TestAsync(CancellationToken ct) 
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        if (somethingOrTheOther) {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }

        await tcs.Task.OrCancelledBy(ct);
    }
```